# what is the width of my blog column?

Tags: content-width

My blog is voraciouslyyours.com

I would like to know the width of my blog column. I have been told that I should make images "twice the width of my clog column" because the retina screens need the double width to display images crisply. I tried finding the width myself using this link http://www.bu.edu/tech/services/comm/websites/www/wordpress/how-to/find-area-width/, but got two different numbers when using chrome tools versus internet explorer. Can anyone verify for my the width of my blog column or help me find it?

Answer (score 1):

While the link you gave gives you correct width, your theme may be responsive and may have different width on different screen sizes.

The best way in this case is to find the maximum width your theme support and then make images 2x that.

To find the maximum width:

1. open your website in Chrome. Right click the blog column → inspect.
2. Now, toggle device mode on. See this link: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/
3. Once done, select 'Responsive' from drop-down at top. Enter a big width, like 1900.
4. Now follow the steps in the tutorial you mentioned.

This should help you with images on all screen sizes.

Comment: P.S. Your blog's maximum width is 625 pixels.